# How can this be solved and to get numbers?

Tags: javascript

```
var tada =document.querySelectorAll("#element > table tr:nth-child(n+0) td:nth-child(1)")[0].outerText
```

this gains first

```
var tada =document.querySelectorAll("#element > table tr:nth-child(n+0) td:nth-child(1)")[1].outerText
```

This kind of text how can it be changed to fit all the values?
How do I change `[0].outerText`

0 to all numbers?

or how to get only the first number from the picture (console.log)

[image]

They just need to get those first numbers the code of the page looks like this
http://jsfiddle.net/8cuagzjd/1/

and yet how to calculate all array?

Comment: Are you after an array like `[19, 20, 20]`?

Comment: @Keith it would be enough to combine them all into one number

19 20 20 for example

I would need from the picture (for the result to be [19, 20, 20])

and then I can't work with multiple arrays to add all three

Comment: @Keith in fact, it would be enough to find all the results instead of one   [1].outerText   
  [1]. change to [^\d: ]

Comment: Something like this -> `var tada =[...document.querySelectorAll("table tr:nth-child(n+0) td:nth-child(1)")].map(m => parseInt(m.outerText, 10)).filter(f => !Number.isNaN(f))` will give you the array.

Comment: @Keith   0: 6172
1: 0
2: 0
3: 2
4: 26
5: 26   is nod ideal dekete this numbers?      array 0 1 2

they are there for more

and how can you mass clean up these other array?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what your saying.  Posting the code above, into the jsFiddle you provided gives. `[19, 20, 20]`...

Comment: @Keith well he probably takes the first 3 numbers from elsewhere

would they go away? the first three results? (and then count the rest)?  I can calculate it, but unfortunately when there was a smaller number of arrays, it didn't calculate anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach,

- There is a NaN element that I didn´t know if you want to remove or remain there.
- The code split the `td` tag and get the last part (after the div). Then just `parseInt()` the value and you will get the number.
- As a result you will get an array with the numbers.

```js
//just commented this for tests purpose
//var tada = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#element > table tr:nth-child(n+0) td:nth-child(1)"));
var tada = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("table tr:nth-child(n+0) td:nth-child(1)"));

let numbers = [];
tada.forEach(e => {
    let num = parseInt(e.innerHTML.split("</div>")[1]);
    //to avoid adding Nan
    if (!isNaN(num))  numbers.push(num);
});

let sum = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

```html
<div class="trainqueue_wrap" id="trainqueue_wrap_barracks">
  <table class="vis" style="width: 100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 25%">Výcvik</th>
        <th>Trvání</th>
        <th>Zhotovení</th>
        <th style="width: 150px">Ukončení *</th>
        <th style="background:none !important; width: 2%"></th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="lit">
        <td class="lit-item">
          <div class="unit_sprite unit_sprite_smaller sword"></div>
          19 Šermířů
        </td>
        <td class="lit-item"><span class="">0:00:37</span></td>
        <td class="lit-item">dnes v 00:42:11 hodin</td>
        <td class="lit-item"><a class="btn btn-cancel" onclick="return TrainOverview.cancelOrder(1645)" href="/">Storno</a></td>
        <td class="lit-item" style="background:none !important;"></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
    <tbody id="trainqueue_barracks">

      <tr class="sortable_row" id="trainorder_0">
        <td class="">
          <div class="unit_sprite unit_sprite_smaller spear"></div>
          20 Kopiníků
        </td>
        <td>0:00:32</td>
        <td>dnes v 00:42:43 hodin</td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-cancel" onclick="return TrainOverview.cancelOrder(1646)" href="/">Storno</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="sortable_row" id="trainorder_1">
        <td class="">
          <div class="unit_sprite unit_sprite_smaller spear"></div>
          20 Kopiníků
        </td>
        <td>0:00:32</td>
        <td>dnes v 00:43:15 hodin</td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-cancel" onclick="return TrainOverview.cancelOrder(1647)" href="/">Storno</a></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="lit-item">
          <a class="evt-confirm btn btn-cancel nowrap" data-confirm-msg="Opravdu chceš zrušit veškerou rekrutaci?" href="">Zrušit vše</a></td>
        <th style="background:none !important;"></th>
      </tr>

    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: and how do I add up all the numbers found together? and thanx

Comment: You mean like concat the numbers in a string?

Comment: example [0]+[1]+[2]+[3] ( array canculation )

Comment: but I think that the numbers are added (array is not the same if the result itself can be adjusted somehow?)

Comment: just remove the first three results @Alexandro Palacios

Comment: sorry I didn't understand

Comment: the first three results are wrong (they repeat the first result)

if there is 3 array (1 2 3) then the script counts 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 +2 +3

Comment: Ahh, ok, in the snippet the sum seems to be right. Glad I could help!